# Why are there two locations for my github python package?

Tags: python, github

I use a python package that I installed from Github. I installed it on a remote university machine.

I think I might have perhaps screwed up the installation in the past / put it in the wrong location or something.

The package works fine. But I would like to clear something up for my own understanding.

I see two folders:

```
1. /home/myusername/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packagename
```

and

```
2. /home/pbrook/packagename
```

I'm just confused as to why there are two locations. Is this because of something that I did wrong when I installed at some point? Or is it not possible to tell from the information I have given.

I'm confused about which version (if they are indeed two versions) python uses and which I should keep up to date.

Any info would be great.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: It was a while back so I'm not certain. I'm thinking that one time I may have git cloned it and then another time, I may have run a setup.py code that did everything. It's not much info I'm sorry.

Comment: Based on your last comment, the first path would be from the setup.py and the latter from using git. Both are correct given their installation methods. The former likely also added the package to pip, which is used to manage and update python packages... and packages managed by pip are typically stored in this location. The later is probably not added to pip and is thus self-managed. Self-managed python packages generally should not be in `~/.local/lib/python*`. You may need to do some investigating to see which one is being used by python... but the one managed by pip is more convenient.

Comment: That does make sense. But looking in my old emails, I see that previously, I have successfully updated by going to "/home/pbrook/packagename" and then doing "pip install --user --upgrade ." - doesn't this mean that I am managing number 2 above using pip? Thank you!